# What is the most "space effective" way to store text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have +10 million articles(200 to 1000 words) in a `InnoDB` table. I only use this type of query when I'm working with `article` field:

```
SELECT article,title,other_fields from table where id=123;
```

**What is the most "space effective" way to store text in MySQL?**

Now the **table size is *say* 100GB, my objective is to make that as little as possible** without causing too much performance tradeoff.

Comment: SELECT doesn't "store". Did you mean "display"?

Comment: im not native but maybe you misread the question?

Comment: Yeah, the code inclusion did throw me off, sorry.

Comment: okay np, i just added an example.

Comment: Delete old articles that nobody reads any more?

Comment: @Mark, its not an option for SEO purposes

Comment: If you don't need to search the contents of `article` you could `compress()` the data on insertion.

Comment: @cOle2 thanks, any idea how much it shrinks?

Comment: @user4220128 Would depend on your text but I'd hazard a guess at about 80%. Take a [look here](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/data-compression-innodb-text) for some example queries to determine how much space you could save.

Comment: @cOle2 Thanks in my case it is about 40% improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM is more space friendly than InnoDB, you can start with that one.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, innodb [compressed rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html) is an option.

You need to be sure that your file_format system parameter is set to Barracuda though.  An attempt to alter to make the row format compressed where row format is the default Antelope may result in a wasted table rebuild only to give you a warning that row format wasn't supported.

I've found the compression on various datasets to not be very good and give a lot of cpu overhead, especially hurting performance where joins are involved.

I've been experimenting to the [TokuDB](http://www.tokutek.com/tokudb-for-mysql/) storage engine for mysql which seems to offer better compression ratios at better speeds, among other benefits (such as quick online schema changes).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content, you might get some good/useful results using a clever lossless compression algorithm. Other than that, you might group texts into batches, and compress that altogether for much better results without a significant performance drop.

It's all about the space/speed proportion.